# Integrating Tumblr "Like" Buttons with Infinite Ajax Scroll (vs. Paul Irish's Infinite Scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr, infinite-scroll, jquery-masonry

**The Issue:**
Non-functioning "Like" buttons on a Tumblr blog using Masonry and Infinite Ajax Scroll.

**My Research:**
I've seen several examples of how to integrate Tumblr's Like buttons with Paul Irish's Infinite Scroll, but the information I've found on how to do so with IAS is less explicit, and unfortunately my JavaScript knowledge is insufficient to piece it together. These are the articles I've consulted:

- tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#like_and_reblog_buttons
- stackoverflow.com/questions/16390193/using-tumblr-like-button-with-infinite-scroll
- stackoverflow.com/questions/18245238/tumblr-like-button-not-working-after-infinite-scroll-ajax-recall
- stackoverflow.com/questions/20789608/how-to-request-tumblr-like-button-status-after-a-new-page-is-loaded-with-infinit
- magnusthemes.tumblr.com/post/132530444620/like-button-with-infinite-scroll-tutorial

**What I've Tried:**
- Added id="{PostID}" to posts, then
- Tried inserting the following into my JS in several different places (in its own function, in the function that appends masonry posts, etc.):

```
var $newPosts = $(data).find('.j-itm');
var $newPostIDs = $newPosts.map(function () {
    return $(this).attr('id');
}).get();
Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids($newPostIDs);
```

...these attempts either broke the masonry layout without fixing the Like buttons, or had no effect at all.

**Code Tester:**
I've created a test blog ([stackoverflow-test](http://stackoverflow-test.tumblr.com)) on Tumblr, with username stackoverflow-test@mailinator.com and password stackoverflowtest. Once logged in go to https://www.tumblr.com/customize/stackoverflow-test to edit and preview the code.

**The Full Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://neuraldamage.com/css/reset.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            .j-msn { padding-bottom: 6em; }  /* masonry container */
            .j-itm { position: relative;  float: left; }  /* masonry item */
            .j-itm, .j-szr--itm { width: 25%; }  /* item sizer */
            .j-szr--gtr { width: 0; }  /* gutter sizer */
            .j-itm img { position: relative;  float: left;  width: 100.1%; }  /* prevent pixel gaps */
            #j-pag { display: none; }  /* pagination */
            .j-nxt {}  /* next page */
            .j-spn { position: absolute;  bottom: 2em;  width: 100%;  text-align: center; }  /* spinner */
            .j-spn__img { display: inline-block;  width: 40px;  height: 40px;  background-size: 100%;
                          background-image: url('https://neuraldamage.com/img/icon/loader-01-black.gif'); }  /* spinner image */
            .j-fin { position: absolute;  bottom: 1em;  z-index: 20;  padding: 0 0.5em; }  /* finished */
            .j-fin__txt { font-style: italic; }  /* finished text */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="[ j-msn ]">
            <div class="[ j-szr--itm ]"></div><div class="[ j-szr--gtr ]"></div>
            {block:Posts}
                {block:Text}
                <div class="[ j-itm ]" id="{PostID}">
                    {block:Title}{Title}{/block:Title}
                    {Body}
                    {LikeButton color="black" size="24"}
                </div>
                {/block:Text}
                {block:Photo}
                <div class="[ j-itm ]" id="{PostID}">
                    {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}">{LinkCloseTag}
                    {LikeButton color="black" size="24"}
                </div>
                {/block:Photo}
            {/block:Posts}
            <ul id="j-pag">
                {block:PreviousPage}<li><a href="{PreviousPage}">&#171; Previous</a></li>{/block:PreviousPage}
                {block:NextPage}<li class="[ j-nxt ]"><a href="{NextPage}">Next &#187;</a></li>{/block:NextPage}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://neuraldamage.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://neuraldamage.com/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://neuraldamage.com/js/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // masonry
                var container = document.querySelector('.j-msn');
                var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
                    itemSelector    : '.j-itm',
                    columnWidth     : '.j-szr--itm',
                    gutter          : '.j-szr--gtr',
                    percentPosition : true
                });
            // infinite ajax scroll
                var ias = $.ias({
                    container      : ".j-msn",
                    item           : ".j-itm",
                    pagination     : "#j-pag",
                    next           : ".j-nxt a",
                    negativeMargin : 200,
                    delay          : 2400
                });
                ias.on('render', function(items) {
                    $(items).css({ opacity: 0 });
                });
                ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
                    msnry.appended(items);
                });
                ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension({
                    src: '<div class="[ j-spn ]"><div class="[ j-spn__img ]"></div></div>',
                }));
                ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({html: '<div class="[ j-fin ]"><h2 class="[ j-fin__txt ]">End.</h2></div>'}));
            // TEST - like buttons
                // function(){
                    // var $newPosts = $(data).find('.j-itm');
                    // var $newPostIDs = $newPosts.map(function () {
                        // return $(this).attr('id');
                    // }).get();
                    // Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids($newPostIDs);
                // });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure this is relatively simple, and I apologize for my extreme JavaScript ignorance!